# Add font-awesome to checkbox

Tags: html, css

I want to add a fa-window-close style to my  
In other words I want to have the window close (X) instead of the checked simbol, when I click the input.

I only want to use html.
How would the syntax look like?

Comment: Sorry for the spelling, here is the text once again:0


I want to add a fa-window-close style to my input tag, in other words I want to have the window close (X) instead of the checked simbol, when I click the input.

I only want to use html. How would the syntax look like?

Comment: What have you tried already? Please make sure the question is following the SO rules.

Comment: You could make a custom checkbox using javascript. Simple change the icon onClick and store the value somewhere in your script, plenty of resources to find for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```css
.checkbox-custom, .radio-custom {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;   
}

.checkbox-custom, .checkbox-custom-label, .radio-custom, .radio-custom-label {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.checkbox-custom-label, .radio-custom-label {
    position: relative;
}

.checkbox-custom + .checkbox-custom-label:before, .radio-custom + .radio-custom-label:before {
    content: '';
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 2px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.checkbox-custom:checked + .checkbox-custom-label:before {
    content: "\f00c";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    background: rebeccapurple;
    color: #fff;
}

.radio-custom + .radio-custom-label:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.radio-custom:checked + .radio-custom-label:before {
    content: "\f00c";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    color: #bbb;
}

.checkbox-custom:focus + .checkbox-custom-label, .radio-custom:focus + .radio-custom-label {
  outline: 1px solid #ddd; /* focus style */
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/6fac2730d4.js"></script>
<form>
  <div>
    <input id="checkbox-1" class="checkbox-custom" name="checkbox-1" type="checkbox" checked>
    <label for="checkbox-1" class="checkbox-custom-label">First Choice</label>
  </div>
</form>
```